# How to Email to mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, outlook-addin

I have PHP/ mySQL based forms on my website where users have to login before they can enter any data/ CRUD functions etc. The data entered by users then shows in a listing/ table below the form. This much is typical...

I was wondering what would be required to be able to send an email from any SMTP email client (say outlook) that enters data in the the mySQL table directly and when the user opens the related screen, the sent data shows in the listing/ table.

1. How would the session be established.
2. Do we need to create a plugin/ addin for outlook client.
3. Is there a free example/ tool available.

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you mean by "enters data into mysql table"? what do you want exacfly?

Comment: An email that is connected to a DB?

Comment: Indeed, your explanations are unclear. Try to better describe the workflow.

Comment: Remember that you can't control any email-client (like Outlook) from PHP, because PHP is a server-side technology. But with PHP you can control the mail server, which decides which informations/data are presented to the client.

Comment: Let’s look at an example. An email is sent by anyone to support@pmanywhere.co. They want to report a problem they encountered while registering to  pmanywhere.co. To see their report I can open my email client and see what was sent. 

Now the same user could have gone to contact us page and filled the form. The form saves the input to the MySQL database. Support team sees this data as a troubleshooting ticket within the application and they act on it. 

Now my question is could the user’s email (instead of contact us form) saved the data in database also so support team sees it as a ticket

Comment: I know there are apps in the market doing such a thing. Don’t know how. By adding something to the email client, letting the user download a tool, or don’t know what else is out there